# How to make the Views Slideshow controls actually work?

Tags: 7, views, javascript

I installed the module Views Slideshow 7.x 3.1, including the dependent modules as well as the jquery.cycle.all.js (version 3.03) in sites/all/libraries/jquery.cycle.

I am able to create a slideshow with a numeric pager showing 1 2 3 for the 3 slides I have added.

However, the pager numbers aren't linked and the previous and next buttons look like links but nothing happens when I click them.

Have searched for a solution but found nothing.

Also, the slideshow doesn't cycle, just stays on the 1st slide.

Comment: Use Chrome DevTools, Firebug or any other debug tool that has the browser that you usually use, to see if there are Javascript errors.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to share the link?

It is also possible that there is a jquery conflict (ran into this issue a while ago). In my case it was superfish + flexslider, both with their own jquery source that were not interchangeable. This lead either the slider not working, or the menu not working.

I solved it by using jQuery.noConflict();
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. Don't want the link published for too long since the slideshow isn't working but it's here: https://internews.org/myanmar-media-slideshow. I will look into the jquery.noconflict().

Comment: Also, not clear from the documentation I've read what files should be in sites/all/libraries/jquery.cycle. Is it just jquery.cycle.all.js or should that be renamed jquery.cycle.all.min.js? And should cycle.jquery.json be there as well? Have tried various combinations with no luck.

Comment: @Patricia I just created a views slideshow on my local test site with no issue. On a side note, firebug shows that "http://openlayers.org/api/2.12/OpenLayers.js" is not being loaded correctly. Make sure it is https:// or just // I would suggest that you look into another slider module (there are a lot) such as Flexslider, as there are unsolved issues similar to yours in the Drupal issue area.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I will check the openlayers.js and look into other modules if I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

[Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) ver. 7.x-3.1 works as advertised.

However, to get any action, you need to enable not only **Views Slideshow**, but also something to cycle the slides (e.g. the **Views Slideshow: Cycle** sub-module).  From your description of the symptoms, it sounds as if you've left the last step out.

Here is a link to a quite detailed [tutorial](http://heim.ifi.uio.no/gisle/staging2/drupalprimer/drupal/mod_views_ss.html) about how to set the whole thing up.